# how to generate a new variable

Tags: variables, stata

I'm trying to create a new variable in Stata that indicates whether a family is in poverty which requires the comparison between two existing variables, both numeric.

Answer (score 0):

When you generate variables, you can use connectors such as "&" for unions and "|" for disjunctions.

For example, let's say you want to create an indicator of poverty using income and household size.  Code could be as follows:

gen povertyIndicator = 0

replace povertyInd = 1 if annualIncome < 15000 & householdSize >= 2

//this incorporates both variables using 'and'

replace povertyInd = 1 if annualIncome < 15000 | householdSize > 3

//this incorporates either variable using 'or'